# Theano: How to implement the distance between desired output (1d) and label as cost function

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, classification, theano

I would like to train a neural network to represent a function from R^n to R.
The neuronal network has only one layer, the input neurons are the function parameters, the output is the function value.
For example, the function could be "logical and": Two input values, one output.

In order to train such a network, I need to define a cost function which can then be derived with Theano's support for gradients.
The problem is:
Usually you would use a neuronal network for classification. A training sample is (input, y) where y is the desired output = index of the output neuron which should have maximum likelihood.

In this case that is impossible, I only have one output neuron and need to compare it with the label => The label is not used for indexing.
In pseudocode:

```
if y==0:
   cost= - output
else:
   cost= - (1-output)
```

With this approach, the cost would have to be recomputed with every sample. Since the formula for computing the cost depends on the value of y.

I believe it is necessary to implement the choice inside of a theano formula.
Something like in this pseudocode:

```
block1= - output
block2= - (1 - output)
blockMatrix= [block1 : block2]
return blockMatrix[y]
```

In the theano tutorials indexing is used in combination with differentiation, so this should work.

**Actual question:**
How does blocking work in theano ?

The types of the symbols in my code: output is a matrix, y is a vector. The samples are created like this, a row is a sample.

```
data_x = numpy.matrix([[0, 0],
                       [1, 0],
                       [0, 1],
                       [1, 1]])

data_y = numpy.array([0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      1])
```

The complete code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/PByUyvMQ
It is mostly exactly like this tutorial: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html

Comment: Are you sure you only need one output neuron ? you can actually have two neurons (One to output '0', second to output '1'), If you do it this way you can use the same cost function as in the example; however, if you want only one output neuron then you are actually doing 'regression', in this case the simplest cost function could be the average distance between your prediction and true label.
Also, I see you are using 'softmax' to compute output (you only have to use softmax to interpret output as a probability), for one output neuron multiplying weight matrix with the input matrix is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what blocking exactly means, but for simply concatenating two tensor variables, there're [`theano.tensor.concatenate()`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) and [`theano.tensor.stack()`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.stack).

Moreover, there's another formulation of your problem that may save from conditioning and blocking:

`cost = -(1-y)*output -y*(1-output)`